# work thing, need help - how to split ranges that overlapping?

Tags: sql, postgresql, overlap, date-range, sql-timestamp

[image: img1]
[image: img2]

I have 3 tsranges that overlap like the figure below, how can I divide them so that we have 0-1 black, 1-2 green, 2-3 black, 3-4 green and 4-5 black? like img2?

i've tryied to agregate them but cant gat the black time between the greens

| id | range | color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 2023-05-05T20:00:345Z to 2023-05-05T22:00:345Z | BLACK |
| 02 | 2023-05-05T20:30:345Z to 2023-05-05T20:42:345Z | GREEN |
| 03 | 2023-05-05T21:00:345Z to 2023-05-05T21:20:345Z | GREEN |

The result should be

| id | range | color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 2023-05-05T20:00:345Z to 2023-05-05T20:30:345Z | BLACK |
| 02 | 2023-05-05T20:30:345Z to 2023-05-05T20:42:345Z | GREEN |
| 03 | 2023-05-05T20:42:345Z to 2023-05-05T21:00:345Z | BLACK |
| 04 | 2023-05-05T21:00:345Z to 2023-05-05T21:20:345Z | GREEN |
| 05 | 2023-05-05T21:20:345Z to 2023-05-05T22:00:345Z | BLACK |

Answer (score 0):

Multiranges are the convenient way to express this.

To get all green ranges, aggregate them:

```
SELECT range_agg(range) FILTER (WHERE color = 'GREEN')
FROM tab;
```

Subtract this from the aggregate of the black ranges to get the remainder:

```
SELECT range_agg(range) FILTER (WHERE color = 'BLACK')
     - range_agg(range) FILTER (WHERE color = 'GREEN')
FROM tab;
```

You can use the `unnest()` function to decompose the multiranges into a table of ranges.

Comment: my postgresql at work dont have range agg, is there another way?

Comment: Perhaps, but that would be complicated. You'll need to upgrade at some point anyway. Why not use the opportunity?